# why this code is not working in chrome,firefox etc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="javascript" src="F:\html\js\jquery.js">
</script>
<script charset="UTF-8" type="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<button>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

" Hi,I am new to jquery. when i am putting direct source path of jquery lib it is working but if saving in local system as jquey.js file not working.Then i saw from net someone had said to change the charset of script tag then I changed but still not working in any browser."

Comment: Because of `F:\html\js\jquery.js`

Comment: You *might* use `src="file:///F:\html\js\jquery.js"` but it would be **much** cleaner to use a relative URL (edit : or a CDN file as suggested by Derek).

Comment: Change it to `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js`

Comment: BTW that's the first time I see a js file served as UTF-16...

Comment: and it has been quite a long time I've seen people using HTML4.01

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 This, unfortunately, I see it from time to time, due to the big amount of obsolete tutorials (and coders) on the net.

Comment: if i am giving https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js it is working fine but in my local jquery.js file not working....

Answer (score 3):

Either refer to the jQuery library online (eg. `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`) or if you want to use your own copy, make sure it's placed under the same directory on your file system as where your file is that you are calling it from; it could be a subdirectory within that directory too. Then you just call it using a relative path instead of a full path, and it will always work (considering you keep the same folder / file structure).

So suppose your html file is under...

```
F:\html\mypage.html
```

...then you could have your jQuery library as you have it right now...

```
F:\html\js\jquery.js
```

...but in your `mypage.html` file (in the `head`) you would call it this way:

```
<script type="javascript" src="js\jquery.js">
```